# Как расспарсить формулу в текстовом формате?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Добый день, подскажите пожалуйста! Функция draft создает график по формуле (в данном случае y = np.sin(t)), функция работает, но есть одна проблема! Для полной реализации нужно вводить формулу вручную и передавать в функцию в виде строки, где в последующем нужно ее распарсить и применить для построения графика.
Пробывал реализовать через алгоритм сортировочной станции, ругается на переменную t, тк она не является числом, она диапазон значений (как я это понял)
Если кто то встречался, отпишитесь, буду очень благодарен за помощь!

PS Формула может быть абсолютно произвольная

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def draft(interval, step, formula):
    start = datetime.datetime.now().day - datetime.timedelta(days=interval).days
    end = datetime.datetime.now().day

    t = np.linspace(start, end, 500)
    # ???
    y = np.sin(t)

    plt.grid()
    plt.xticks(np.arange(start, end, step))
    plt.plot(t, y)
    plt.show()


draft(interval=6, step=2, formula="sin(t)")
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) https://stackoverflow.com/q/35430479/7485582

Answer (score 0):

Регулярные выражения - сила. `r'(?P<func>[\w\d]+)\((?P<arg>[\w\d]+)\)'` и считать найденные группы. должны увидеть `'sin'` и `'t'`

Проверить можно тут https://regex101.com/r/Nso1sr/1

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но немножко не то, формула может быть абсолютно произвольная